# Sound settings missing after removing PulseAudio

Tags: release-freya, audio

OK, so I messed around with PulseAudio and purged all of it. Now my regular sound settings do not work anymore. neither can I turn up and down the volume with the respective keys, nor do the sound settings show any devices (neither input nor output). The sound symbol does not show in the menu bar anymore either. I can hear sound though.

I guess I accidentally uninstalled a package that is needed. Does anybody know which packages I have to reinstall?

Comment: Why did you decide to purge PulseAudio? It's a terrible decision to remove packages which purpose you do not understand. Did something point you that way?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot :) I was trying to stream to Airtunes and it didn't work so I was impatient and thought a reinstall would be a good idea (which it was not). Lesson learned ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalling the system (I suppose just the pulseaudio packages would have done too) the problem was that the config files in my home folder - which I hadn't deleted because I didn't format my home folder - were apparently corrupted and caused a malfunction. Thus, I deleted

> ~/.config/pulse
>
> ~/.gconf/system/pulseaudio

and restarted the system. And voilà, everything works again. The sound button in the menu bar is back, and I can use keys to control the volume.

Answer (score 2):

PulseAudio is the sound server. It is necessary for all of the functions that are now broken on your system. You need to reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you - I did a clean reinstall of the OS to be sure it worked. But now it gets a little weird: Sound is working normally; however there is still no symbol in the menu bar. BUT there is a little space between the symbols for language and wifi, and when I click there the regular drop down menu appears and I can e.g. control Music or Banshee - but the volume bar is greyed out and I cannot change the volume. I then installed pavucontrol and when I try to open it there is an error message that reads:

"Fatal Error: Unable to connect to PulseAudio: OK"

Any ideas? and thank you again!

Comment: Also, in the system settings there aren't any sound devices showing, neither input nor output

Comment: Controlling the volume with alsamixer works though

Comment: The sound symbol in the menu bar is back because I turned it on using dconf (com/canonical/indicator/sound/visible). Doesn't change the problem though, the volume control is greyed out and I cannot use the volume +/- keys on the keyboard either

Comment: @luett Since it seems you're having a new problem unrelated to this question, can you please open a new question?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a new problem - the problematic behavior is very similar to the one before the reinstall. It might well be that I just didn't try to click on the spot where the sound symbol in the menu bar usually appears. The sound was there before, also that I couldn't use the keyboard to control the volume is the same. Could it be that one of the configuration files of Pulseaudio on my home drive (which I didn't format) is causing the problem (e.g. not starting pulseaudio properly)? Would it maybe be sufficient deleting the configuration files and restart or reinstall the system?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use pulse audio, didnt work so i deleted it like the first guy, my headphones, speakers and usb dac/amp (IKKO ITM01s) died, then installed QasMixer and the headphone jack and speakers work, but not my usb dac/amp, everything was fixed when I installed pipewire with this guide and regained control from the sound panel

## Add ppa for latest build

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream

## Update

sudo apt update

## Install components

sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-pipewire pipewire-media-session libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack pipewire pipewire-audio-client-libraries

## If you get unmet dependencies, you can run:

sudo apt --fix-broken install

## Then re-run

sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-pipewire pipewire-media-session libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack pipewire pipewire-audio-client-libraries

## Reload new services

systemctl --user daemon-reload

## Disable PulseAudio service

systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket

## If you update from previous version of PopOS

systemctl --user mask pulseaudio

## Enable Pipewire services

systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse

## Enable Pipewire media session

systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service